# VBA Script Error: "Sub or Function not defined"

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code which is supposed to open up a specified windows directory and then one by one process all Excel (.xls) files in that location.  To be more specific the code will open an excel file, take the name given to the worksheet and place that name/value into cell A1 of that worksheet and then save and close the file.  It will then move onto the next Excel file in the directory.

The problem I face is that on executing the code I get the following compile error: "Sub or Function not defined".  I am just unable to figure out what is causing this error.

Please see code witten below:

```
Sub UseSheetName()
    selectedfolder = GetFolder("c:\")
    Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedfolder)
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath

        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Function updateAllWorkbooks(workDir)
    Dim fso, f, fc, fl
    Dim newName As String, appStr As String, SubDir As String

    On Error GoTo updateAllWorkbooks_Error

    SubDir = workDir & "\" & "ConvertedFiles"
    If Not fExists(SubDir) Then
        MkDir SubDir
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.GetFolder(workDir)
    Set fc = f.Files

    For Each fl In fc
        If Right(fl, 4) = ".xls" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=fl
            ActiveSheet.[a1] = ActiveSheet.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

updateAllWorkbooks_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure updateAllWorkbooks of Module Module2"
End Function
```

Comment: When you compile with such an error, the offending code is highlighted. So looking at your screen should give you the answer. And anyway, you should tell in your question where the error happens.

Comment: It highlights it in the editor. fExists is not a command.

Comment: Usethe FileSystemObject Returns True if a specified folder exists; False if it does not. `object.FolderExists(folderspec)`

Comment: hello, it's been a LONG time since i looked at vb/vba code. one thing that MIGHT help is to add *option explicit* at the top of the code module. this means that any variables that are undefined (and or function that don't exist) are captured in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is all of your code, then you do not have a function defined as `fExists`. So it will fail on the line `If Not fExists(SubDir) Then` as the Function `fExists` is not defined.

Comment: Hi Thank you all for the quick response. As identified the FExists function was missing. I have updated the above code with the follwing function included and it now works fine.


Many Thanks again for all your help.

Regards,

Comment: user378.. - you should give this answer an upvote plus mark it as the correct answer for future visitors

Comment: Jim, you are correct.  So the following lines were added to my original code for it to work.  As stated the fExist function was added.


Function fExists(newName As String) As Boolean
    Dim tester As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    tester = GetAttr(newName)
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 0
        fExists = True
    Case Else
        fExists = False
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Comment: There is no point putting On Error <anything> as the last statement in a function. It is reset to the parent's function setting on End Sub/Function.

Comment: As the answer given has solved your original question, please Upvote and Mark as the answer.